# I want to run 2 for loops concurrently, is it possible?

Tags: python

there are 2 loops i want to run, loop_1 and loop_2 
i want to run them concurrently 
but its not working it run only 1 loop

```
# i've tried this one
import pyautogui
import time
import loop_1

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
times = interval=input("Enter speed: ")
text = input("Enter Text you want to repeat: ")
loops = int(input("Amount of repeats: "))

time.sleep(5)

for x in range(loops):
    pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.01)
    pyautogui.typewrite(text, times)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    pyautogui.typewrite(text, times)
    pyautogui.press('enter')

# loop_1

for i in range(100):
        pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.01)

# loop_2

for x in range(loops):
    pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.01)
    pyautogui.typewrite(text, times)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    pyautogui.typewrite(text, times)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
```

its not working it just stuck in loop_1, i want it to run both the loops at the same time

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Dig towards [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: This is a classic concurrency problem.  Python has libraries to enable this.

Answer (score 1):

Use multi-threading to run loops at the same time. Search for the keyword and you will find lots of tutorials about it. For example :

```
#import threading

'''
your code
'''
# loop_1
def loop1():
    for i in range(100):
        pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.01)

# loop_2
def loop2(loops):
    for x in range(loops):
        pyautogui.press('enter', interval=0.01)
        pyautogui.typewrite(text, times)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.typewrite(text, times)
        pyautogui.press('enter')

# Create two threads as follows
# target = executed function, args = parameter to be passed
t1 = threading.Thread(target=loop1, args=()) 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=loop2, args=(loops,)) 

# starting thread 1 
t1.start() 
# starting thread 2 
t2.start() 

# Now loop1 and loop2 are keep being executed

# Use join() to stop execution of current program until both loops are complete
# wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
t1.join() 
# wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
t2.join()
```

Comment: so, it'll first complete first loop and then goes for second loop, right?

Comment: @AceDasXanTv, No, as gameon67 said, the code does "run loops at the same time."

Comment: @AceDasXanTv Once the threads start, both loops will keep executing. We use `t1.join() t2.join()` to stop execution of current program until both loops are complete, then after that execute the rest of your code.

Comment: the program runs quite perfect followed by gameon67 but, it stop holding "enter" here is the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE7yb.jpg

Comment: @AceDasXanTv what do you mean? You didn't explain your program workflow or intention on your question. I don't know how your program suppose to work